FME Form - Transpose and Pair up data, can I do it with a List?
I am trying to transpose some data from a survey, I want to sort of Pair up the Postcode and the Question Number, then have columns of Responses with counts. Ive attached images  and a fme workbench of the original data and the output I want. I have 36 questions, so want to know if there is a way to do this using a list? So I dont have to repeat this 36 times, I am not understanding how to do lists!
I want to output the postcode as a column, then have a question number column. So each postcode will be repeated depending on the number of questions, then have the responses with count per pcode & question e.g.
Question No    Postcode     Agree Neither Disagree
Question 1      M19 4NY  1  3 4
Question 2     M19 4NY  2 4 5
Question 1      M4 7AT  1 4 6
Question 2     M4 7AT 2 5 7

I have also attached the FME workbench of how I want to format the data, but Im having to repeat if 36 times as there are 36 questiona - can I do it with a list or something else to save time?


StatsCalculator is useful for this type of attribution summarizing by group.
Example (FME 2024 used):

If understand your logic here, in the StaticsCalculator you can groupby postcode and sum the number of questions
M19 4NY has 9 disagrees (q1+q2)

\ #Mapperz Thanks, thats part of the way there but I need a column for the question number also, as there are multiple questions!
